# Cosmos DB provider in Entity Framework Core throwing 400 BadRequest

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've integrated Cosmos DB in my ASP.NET Core API project, using the latest EF Core package that ships with a Cosmos DB provider.

I'm able to successfully use this provider when running locally in my local ASF cluster, connecting to a local Cosmos DB emulator instance. However, when trying to either run in local ASF or Azure-hosted ASF, I'm unable to connect to the Azure Cosmos DB instance. For some reason I keep getting a 400 BadRequest when initializing the seed for the database/collection.

It's the following line that is generating an error:

```
var created = await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

Exception:

> BadRequest
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsOnceAsync(DbContext _, String collectionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Infrastructure.SystemDataContextSeed.SeedAsync(SystemDataContext context) in Infrastructure\SystemDataContextSeed.cs:line 21
>          at xtensions.IWebHostExtensions.Seed(IWebHost webhost) in Extensions\IWebHostExtensions.cs:line 23
>          at Api.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1(String url, AspNetCoreCommunicationListener listener) in AccountApi.cs:line 47
>          at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreCommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.OpenCommunicationListenersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

What I've tried:

- Analysing log analytics, shows no logging for these requests
- Removing the EnsureCreated and just directly insert data
- Create the collection manually (SystemDataContext)
- Create the database manually (AccountService)
- Removing networking firewall (Allow all networks) in azure

The endpoint details used are in the form of:

```
"Cosmos": {
    "EndPoint": "https://xxxx-sqlapi.documents.azure.com:443",
    "AuthKey": "xxx==",
    "DatabaseName": "AccountService"
  },
```

Extension method to hook up the Cosmos DB provider:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCosmosSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkCosmos()
                   .AddDbContext<SystemDataContext>(options =>
                   {
                       options.UseCosmos(configuration["Cosmos:EndPoint"], configuration["Cosmos:AuthKey"], configuration["Cosmos:DatabaseName"]); ;
                   },
                       ServiceLifetime.Scoped  //Showing explicitly that the DbContext is shared across the HTTP request scope (graph of objects started in the HTTP request)
                   );

            return services;
        }
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've only posted the *stacktrace* of the exception - but not the actual exception with its exception message and possible inner exceptions. Please post this vital information, too!

Comment: Actually it is, the message is just 'BadRequest', nothing more... And there's no inner exception, sorry if that was not clear!

Comment: There must be some extra error data you are missing. BadRequest is very generalised and usually comes with an explanation.

Comment: I wish... I've been digging into this for a while, but the Stacktrace here is all there is... I wonder if it has something to do with the collection name, after digging in the repository. I haven't specified it at all, but it works on localhost...

Comment: For reference, I've created an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14123 apparently not any request to an azure hosted cosmos db instance works. There are missing headers that are preventing it from successfully creating collections,documents, ...

Comment: I know this was a while back, but we are having the same problem (using dotnet 2.2.0 - latest preview). Has this ever been solved? This happens randomly on a FindOrDefault() when inserting a list of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, the Cosmos DB provider in EF Core 2.2 is a preview, and is not suitable for use against an Azure-hosted Cosmos DB.
This is because in some places, headers are missing that are apparently not an issue for the emulator, but cause a 400 when exeuting against Azure.

The issue I was looking at the longest, was the fact that I got a 400 when it was trying to create the document collection. After digging in the EF Core sourcecode, I saw that it did not sent any partition keys. There is actually no implementation of partition keys at all in the current Cosmos DB implementation. And because I created a database in Azure with shared throughput across collections, you are required to provide a partition key on collection level apparently.

Comment: Does this basically mean, there is no solution to this problem? What is the alternative?

Comment: Not with the preview version AFAIK. I stripped EF from our solution and used Cosmonaut. At least now I know what is happening...

Comment: You can always create your own DB Initiator, using the CosmosClient, and put your partition keys in every collection.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with a newly created CosmosDB account. Some things worked, but I was also getting errors like this 400 one for EF Core EnsureCreated() call, and also 404 when trying to skip that one and just .SaveChanges().

I ended up deleting that CosmosDB account and created a new one, this time everything worked OK.

I used Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos (6.0.0).

Oh, and I created the new CosmosDB account in a "Default-Web-EastUS" resource group, whereas the previous attempt used "Default-Storage-EastUS" one. I doubt this matters but wanted to note everything down, in case I have to google my own answer in the future ;-)